MYSQL DATE_FORMAT returns weird result
select DATE_FORMAT('2099-01-12T23:59:59.999999999:00', '%H:%i:%s');

Result: 00:00:00
Why? I want 23:59:59
2099-01-12T23:59:59.999999999:00 I get as parameter of type LocalDateTime from Java method
How to do that?
I also tried select CAST('2099-01-12T23:59:59.999999999:00' as TIME); but the result is null

what's with the extra ":00" at the end of your data?

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(LEFT('2099-01-12T23:59:59.999999999:00', 19), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s'), '%H:%i:%s');

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that MySQL does not natively handle the fractional seconds or the time zone part of your date string . The DATE_FORMAT function expects a standard datetime string.
To handle this, you need to strip off the fractional seconds and the timezone part of your string before passing it to the DATE_FORMAT

Works! Thanks a lot

MySQL does support fractional seconds, but only up to microseconds. You can use LEFT(..., 26) and get the same result.
